# Use regex to extract multiple values from one string in single call

Tags: objective-c, regex

I am seeking a way to extract from this string:

```
"Per 100g - Calories: 274kcal | Fat: 14.08g | Carbs: 35.71g | Protein: 3.49g"
```

the following:

```
"100g", "247", "14.08", "35.71", "3.49"
```

Here's what I tried:

```
   NSString *patternString = @"Per (.*) - Calories: (\\d*)kcal | Fat: (\\d*.\\d*)g | Carbs: (\\d*.\\d*)g | Protein: (\\d*.\\d*)g";
    regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:patternString options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSLog(@"length of overall matches is %d", (int)[matches count]);
    parsedString = [stringToParse substringWithRange:[matches[0] rangeAtIndex:1]];
    NSLog(@"and here is the parsed string %@", parsedString);
```

but I only get 1 match capturing the first group and that just returns `100g` and not anything else. Is there some way to extract all these numbers in 1 fell swoop? Notice that the `Per ___` is a variable string, and won't always be in the form of a certain number of grams.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the "|" characters in the pattern:

```
NSString *text = @"Per 100g - Calories: 274kcal \\| Fat: 14.08g \\| Carbs: 35.71g \\| Protein: 3.49g";
NSRange   searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, text.length);
NSString *patternString = @"Per (.*) - Calories: (\\d*)kcal \\| Fat: (\\d*.\\d*)g \\| Carbs: (\\d*.\\d*)g";
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:patternString options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSTextCheckingResult* match = [regex firstMatchInString:text options:0 range: searchedRange];
for (int group = 1; group<match.numberOfRanges; group++) {
    NSLog(@"match %i: %@", group, [text substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:group]]);
}
```

Output:

> match 1: 100g
>   match 2: 274
>   match 3: 14.08
>   match 4: 35.71